# Rails Jquery Mobile Radio Button Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I have been trying to get a dynamic radio button form working in my mobile (JQM) rails 3 app for about 1 week now.

Here is what I need:
Dynamic radio button selection, with JQM Control Group, radio button styling. And I need the user needs to be able to submit it with a submit button.

This seems fairly simple, but I have found almost no documentation on radio_button_tags with dynamic inputs, and the JQM complication makes it even harder. Here is my current form. If someone could point out a resource I could look at, or help me with the code I would greatly appreciate it.

```
<%= form_for(@participation) do |f| %>
<% if @participation.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
         <h2><%= pluralize(@participation.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this participation from being saved:</h2>
         <ul>
            <% @participation.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %> 


<div data-role="content">

    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <input type="radio" name="team_1" id="team_id_1" value="off">
        <label for="team_id_1">Team 1 Name</label>
        <% @teams.each do  |team| %>
            <%= radio_button_tag "participation[team_id]", team.id, team.event_id == @event.id %> <%= team.professional.id %>
            // I've tried this label, but it does not work <%= label :team_id, team.professional.name %>
        <% end %>
    </fieldset>
<%= f.submit "Join" %>
```

With no styling I can get the form to submit, so that part is done. However, when I try to add the JQM styling it breaks.

Thanks.

Comment: You may need to enhance markup using `.checkboxradio('refresh')` but I don't how with ruby.

Comment: Thanks Omar. That gave me the direction I needed. The solution I came up with is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I found to the problem after quite a struggle. Hopefully this helps someone else. Another big thing I discovered, unlike most browsers, Safari does not behave normally when in View Page Source mode. It will not load page content properly, or react to interactions properly.

```
<div data-role="content">

    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <% @teams.each do  |team| %>    
            <%= radio_button_tag "participation[team_id]", team.id, team.event_id == @event.id %>
            <label for="participation_team_id_<%= team.id %>"><%= team.professional.name %> | <%= team.exercise.name %></label>
        <% end %>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<br></br>   
<%= f.submit "Join" %>
```